# Converting Set<byte[]> to List<String>

Tags: java, redis

I'm using redis in memory database in my application. We are adding to a set some string values using the sAdd method and fetching the values from set using the smembers method. This method is returning a Set<byte[]>. I need to convert this set to a list of String. I tried the below way but it is not working.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList((servKeys)).toArray();
```

Comment: What doe the `byte[]` represent? Are they actually text, do you know the encoding? Or is it arbitrary binary data (such as images, encrypted data, ...)? *Why* do you need `String`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Base64` encoder with Stream API:

```
List<String> list = servKeys.stream()
    .map(bytes -> Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively to `Base64`, you can use `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

This depends on what kind of data `byte[]` is. The code above assumes a plain text, however, you can easily adjust the behavior.

Comment: Which one of those makes sense really depends on what the original `byte[]` is ... blindly applying this can be a bad idea.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: That's a very valid point. As long as Redis was tagged I assume the plain text (might be JSON, then the deserialization is needed). I edit my answer to point it out. however, the basic idea of my answer is still valid.